# fclose() crashing c program

Tags: c, fclose

I have a relatively simple program that keeps crashing after reading integers from a file. It crashes upon execution of the fclose line. I have localized the error to be in this function.

```
// Read array from text file
int * fileRead() {
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    // Check if the file exists
    if(file == NULL){
        printf("There was a problem opening the file");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Count number of lines in file
    int count = 0;
    char c;
    for (c = getc(file); c != EOF; c = getc(file)){
        if (c == '\n') { 
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }

    // Reset to top of file
    int t = fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    // Read each line and save it to temp
    int *temp = malloc(sizeof(int)*count);
    int num, i;
    for (i = 0; i<=count; i++){
        fscanf(file, "%d\n", &temp[i]);
        printf("%d\n", temp[i]);
    }

    fclose(file);
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return temp;
}
```

The Hello World is to prove to myself it crashes at fclose exactly. The function reads ints from a file which contains only ints on separate lines (of unknown quantity) and saves them to an array and then returns that array. Thank you in advance for the help, this is my first time using c so I am not sure where to start looking for the bug.

Comment: Does the following fix it ? `; i<count;`.

Comment: It fixed the crash, which is good, but the pointer out put is still messed up. That's a start tho so thank you!

Comment: try `fscanf(file, "%d\n", temp[i]);`

Comment: @TonyTannous: No, don't try that.  You need to pass a pointer to `fscanf()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `int* temp` ?

Comment: @TonyTannous: The variable `temp` is a pointer to an array of `int` (assuming `malloc()` succeeds — technically, that should be checked).  Therefore `&temp[i]` is the pointer to the `i`th element of the array.  `temp[i]` is the value in the `i`th element of the array; that is both undefined and not a pointer anyway.

Comment: In principle, you should check that `fscanf()` is finding 1 item (`if (fscanf(…) != 1) { …error handling… }`).  You know how many lines are in the file; you don't know that each line contains (only) an integer value.  Also, the `fscanf(file, "%d\n", …)` format is dangerous.  Since you are reading from a file, you're OK, but in interactive input (from a terminal), it is disastrous.  The input doesn't stop until the scan comes across a non-digit after any (optional) white space, including newlines.  It means a user typing to the prompt must enter the first non-blank character of the next input.

Comment: @MatthewCaixeiro I edited my answer again. I counted the lines in much proper way so you don't count empty lines and allocate extra memory

Comment: the question is a run time problem.  so the posted code needs to cleanly compile (including a `main()` function so we know how the problem function is being called) and the appropriate `#include` statements need to be posted, so we are not guessing as to which headers you actually used.  you need to post a short sample of the input file,  This is so we can duplicate the problem so we can help you

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling the `fseek()` function, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the function: `getc()` returns an `int`, not a `char` and in many/most cases, cannot successfully compare a `char` to EOF

Comment: the last line of a text file may (or may not) have a trailing newline, so if any characters read on the current line when EOF is encountered, need to add 1 to the line count

Comment: when calling any of the heap memory allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the posted code leaks memory because it calls `malloc()` without a corresponding call to `free()`.  You should not assume the OS will correct that problem for you.

Comment: when outputting an error message, it should be output to `stderr` not `stdout`.  `printf()` outputs to `stdout`.  Suggest `perror()` as it outputs to `stderr` AND outputs the text message related to the current value of `errno` so can tell you what the OS thinks was the problem.

Comment: in the call to `fscanf()` the format string should not contain the trailing `\n'.  Amongst other reasons, the format specifier `%d` will skip leading white space and the '\n' is white space.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTES:**

Indices in c starts from 0. So if you want to save `count` integers, you have to iterate till `count-1`.

`i.e.`

- `i < count`
- `i <= count-1`

Your reading is wrong, as you assume your integers are of one digit.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int * fileRead() {
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("PATH.txt", "r");

    // Check if the file exists
    if(file == NULL){
        printf("There was a problem opening the file");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Count number of lines in file
    int count = 0;
    char pc = '\n';
    char c;
    while (c = fgetc(file), c != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\n'  &&  pc != '\n')
            count++;
        pc = c;
    }

      // Reset to top of file
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    // Read each line and save it to temp
    int *temp = malloc(sizeof(int)*count);
    int num, i;

    for (i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        fscanf (file, "%d", &temp[i]);
    }

    fclose(file);
    return temp;
}


int main()
{
    int *t = fileRead();
    printf("%d\n", t[0]);
    printf("%d\n", t[1]);
}
```

**FILE:**

```
452
55
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
542
55
```

**To sum it up:**

> fclose() crashing my program.

No. It wasn't `fclose` it was you trying to access memory not allocated.

Comment: the method suggested for counting the lines has the same flaw as the OPs posted code, I.E. if the last line does not contain a '\n' then the line count will be 1 too low

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `fgetc(fp)` returns an `int` value that can have all the values of type `unsigned char` and the special value `EOF`.  You must store this into a variable of type `int` for the end of file test to be reliable.
- in the loop `for (i = 0; i<=count; i++){` you cause a buffer overflow as the maximum allowed index into the allocated block is `count-1`.  This is definitely causing undefined behavior and may well explain the observed behavior.

  Use this instead:

  ```
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) ...
  ```
- you must pass the length of the allocated array back to the caller.
- counting the number of lines does not accurately determine the number of entries in the file. It would be better to parse the file twice or to parse it just once and reallocate the array dynamically. The latter approach is necessary  for non seekable input streams such as terminals and pipes.

Here is a modified version of your code:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int *fileRead(int *countp) {

    // Check if the file exists
    FILE *file = fopen("PATH.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open input file PATH.txt: %s\n",
                strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    // Count number of lines in file
    int num, count = 0;
    while (fscanf(file, "%d", &num) == 1) {
        count++;
    }

    // Reset to top of file
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    // Read each line and save it to temp
    int *temp = calloc(sizeof(int), count);
    if (temp != NULL) {
        int i;    
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (fscanf(file, "%d", &temp[i]) != 1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "error reading element number %d\n", i);
                break;
            }
        }
        *countp = i;  // number of entries successfully converted
    }
    fclose(file);
    return temp;
}

int main(void) {
    int count;
    int *t = fileRead(&count);
    if (t != NULL) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            printf("%d\n", t[i]);
        }
        free(t);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this line: `int i; ` does not initialize `i`.  This line: `for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {`  masks the prior `i` variable and the enclosed `i` does not exist when the `for` code block is executed: When this line is executed: `*countp = i;` `i` is still not initialized  so the callers' `countp` will be set to trash.

Comment: @user3629249: good catch! there was a missing `file` argument to the first `fscanf()`... It looks like I did not try and compile before posting ;-)